# ¿Cómo adaptarlo a InternetExplorer 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Tengo este codigo Javascript que me descarga un archivo `CSV`.

En Chrome funciona perfectamente pero en IE8/IE11 no.

```js
  var csv = "sep=,\nMatrícula:,\nDepartamento:,\nNombre:,Rrhh Desarrollador 01,\nTeléfono:,,\nFactoría:,\nEmail:,RRHH.Desarrollador01@prueba.com, BDSWDesk-Request.ES@prueba.com,\nEmpresa:,";

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + escape(csv));
    link.setAttribute("download", "prueba.csv");
    link.click();
```

No da ningun tipo  de error en consola. Lo ejecuta todo pero no descarga el archivo.

He probado creando un elemento blob pero solo vale para IE10+

```js
var csv = "sep=,\nMatrícula:,\nDepartamento:,\nNombre:,Rrhh Desarrollador 01,\nTeléfono:,,\nFactoría:,\nEmail:,RRHH.Desarrollador01@prueba.com, BDSWDesk-Request.ES@prueba.com,\nEmpresa:,";

var a = document.createElement('a'),
  file = new Blob([csv], {
    type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF'
  });
if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) window.navigator.msSaveBlob(file, "prueba.csv");
else {
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file), a.download = "prueba.csv";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}
```

Como *posible* solución, el `execCommand -> SaveAs` (gracias a la respuesta de Guillermo) pero me parece engorroso ya que abre una ventana nueva con el texto `csv` como cuerpo de la pagina web y luego abre dialogo de descarga donde pone  que descargarás un `.html` pese a que es `.csv`

```
var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
oWin.document.writeln(csv);
oWin.document.close();

oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, "prueba.csv")
oWin.close();
```

Pero no funciona con Chrome ni con IE11... y quiero tener el minimo numero de codigos para diferentes navegadores...

**¿Cómo lo hago compatible para IE8 sin usar `execCommand`?**

Comment: Intenté abrir esta página en IE11 en modo de IE8. Si la abre pero muchas de las características no, por ejemplo, no se muestra el botón Ejecutar de los fragmentos de código JavaScript.

Comment: ¿ y si cambias `data:text/csv;...` por `data:image/jpeg;...` ? no tengo IE para probarlo, e IE8 solo soporta ese esquema para imágenes.

Comment: @trauma por que cambiar a imagen? no lo pillo. eso es configuracion del archivo, no de la descarga no?

Comment: @lois6b Porque IE8 solo soporta eso para imágenes; pero no creo que *examine* los datos, sino que se basará en el `mime` que tu le indicas; si le dices `text/csv`, no quedrá. Tal vez si le dices que es un `imagen/jpeg` esté conforme. De todas formas, el nombre del archivo se lo indicas tu, y es independiente del `mime` que le indiques.

Comment: @trauma el problema de mi primer ejemplo es el attributo download, y en el segundo el uso de Blob, ... no creo que cambiar csv a imagen afecte. Voy a pobar. (nada, no ha colado)

Comment: Ah, pues entonces olvida lo que te he dicho. En Google decian que IE no soportaba `data:XXX` si no era con imágenes; no tengo IE8 (ni ningún otro) para probar, así que solté lo primero que se me ocurrió. En fín, por intentarlo que no quede :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
var IEwindow = window.open();
IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV));
IEwindow.document.close();
IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
IEwindow.close();
```

[Aquí un pequeño tutorial de como descargar csv y json multiplataforma](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/07/download-json-data-in-csv-format-cross-browser-support/)

Comment: Cambia la segunda línea por esto 
    IEwindow.document.write(‘sep=,\r\n’ + CSV);

Comment: Si, he leido el enlace entero que pasaste. eso solo indica el separador que ha de usar excel y ya lo tengo incluido en mi variable. No hace que sea compatible con IE

Comment: Guillermo, si ves mi edit, ves que si ha funcionado, pero no se por que antes no ... (quizá el `window.open("about:blank", "_blank");`)  además no vale para IE11, solo IE8 :/

Comment: Si no encuentro otra solucion pasado unos dias, te marco como valida ^^ gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado ;)

Comment: Nada, me he cansado de buscar y metodos que me han ido diciendo por chat no valen.. me quedaré con esto que funciona ^^ gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo que pruebes la librería [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

**Breve explicación**

Esta librería es una minúscula biblioteca JavaScript + Flash que te permite generar archivos a la vez, en el navegador, sin interacción con el servidor. Las aplicaciones web que le permiten generar vCards, paletas de colores, código personalizado, etc. se beneficiarían al usar esta biblioteca. Además de incrementar la velocidad (sin un viaje de ida y vuelta al servidor), esta solución puede reducir la carga de bases de datos y servidores de las aplicaciones web existentes. Esta no es una biblioteca para 'forzar la descarga' de un archivo desde un servidor. No interactúa con un servidor en absoluto.

**Dependencias**

El usuario final debe tener Flash 10 o superior instalado para que este plugin funcione.

Downloadify sólo depende de SWFObject 2.0 que se incluye con la descarga. Es compatible con cualquier framework de JavaScript pero tiene un ayudante para jQuery y MooTools...

Tienen una [página de demo](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html), puedes probar su funcionamiento en línea.

Comment: Bueno, depender de flash en este caso creo no sería tan malo, teniendo en cuenta que se trata de IE8, es decir, Windows XP.

Comment: Estuve un rato preguntandome como funcionaba el ejemplo online. solo a veces sale el boton! :O  además, para su uso he de guardarlo en el servidor (o se puede usar `<script>`? ) y no tengo acceso a él, por eso usaba javascript .

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Vi la posibilidad de esa biblioteca y quise compartirlo, como una posibilidad. Es cuestión de probar si satisface tus necesidades en este caso.

Comment: @Iois6b _Esta librería es una minúscula biblioteca JavaScript + Flash que te permite generar archivos a la vez, en el navegador, sin interacción con el servidor._ Funciona todo del lado del cliente. ¿Cómo funciona? Pues creo que flash hace una lectura/escaneo del div que contiene el texto y crea a partir de ahí un archivo que lo guardas en local. Yo usé una librería parecida que me copiaba en el portapapeles el contenido de un div determinado usando flash, sólo que en Safari daba algún problema, pues no me copiaba los formatos (negrita, cursiva, etc).