# Descargar fichero con el atributo download en IE-11

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy descargando ficheros con html.

Estoy usando `<a href="rutaArchivo.pdf" download="topSecret.pdf">download</a>` Este código funciona para chrome y para mozilla, el problema viene que tengo que hacer la descarga también para IE-11 (12 no).

Además no puedo agregar el target="_blank" porque no se quiere que el archivo se vea en otra pestaña.

He estado leyendo algunas cosas como por ejemplo poner las cabeceras:

```
<? 
 header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
 header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=arch.pdf"); 
 readfile("arch.pdf"); 
?>
```

El problema es que yo no uso PHP. 
Realmente la estructura interna tampoco puedo tocarla, uso la herramienta de IBM  que me va a devolver los datos que necesito, pero no tengo acceso a la forma en que trabaja internamente para poder añadir cabeceras.. es decir, lenguaje del servidor, un ejemplo:

```
</p>hola [dame nombre]</p>
<a href="[dame ruta].[dame extension]" download="[dame nombreFichero].[dame extension]">download</a>
```

Por lo qué a lo único que tengo acceso es a los atributos HTML, por ejemplo, con el atributo download se descarga para Chrome y mozilla pero no para IE-11.

¿ Qué puedo hacer ?

Comment: aqui sale alguna solución con javascript, igual te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie

Comment: O esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55712/19610.

Comment: Tambien te sugiero revisar la longitud de la URL de tu archivo...es decir no debe ser muy extensa xq esto causa problemas en IE es algo extraño pero a mi me funciono...busca la manera de reducir la URL